# Mongo $in operator performance

Tags: mongodb

Is it slow/poor form to use the `$in` operator in MongoDB with a large array of possibilities?

```
posts.find({
    author : {
        $in : ['friend1','friend2','friend3'....'friend40'] 
    }
})
```

App Engine, for example, won't let you use more than 30 because they translate directly to one query per item in the IN array, and so instead force you into using their method for handling [fan out](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16952419/Building-scalable-complex-apps-on-App-Engine).  While that's probably the most efficient method in Mongo too, the code for it is significantly more complex so I'd prefer to just use this generic method.

Will Mongo execute these `$in` queries efficiently for reasonable-sized datasets?

Comment: Have you some index on your author field ?

Comment: Hello @Derek Dahmer , could you overcome this issue? I've been dealing with this issue. This architect named Edge Collection by MongoDB today :)  Me too want to use $in parameter with huge arrays. But I beware the performance impact!   http://image.slidesharecdn.com/socialitept2-140724104718-phpapp01/95/socialite-the-open-source-status-feed-part-2-managing-the-social-graph-18-638.jpg?cb=1406222239

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It can be fairly efficient with small lists (hard to say what small is, but at least into the tens/hundreds) for `$in`. It does not work like app-engine since *mongodb* has actual btree indexes and isn't a column store like bigtable.

With `$in` it will skip around in the index to find the matching documents, or walk through the whole collection if there isn't an index to use.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whats the difference between b-tree and column stores that makes GAE need to have each be a separate query?  Couldn't GAE also just skip around the index?

Comment: Well, AFAIK indexes in appengine are implemented on top of the column store. That means you are limited to range queries and can't skip around in memory as easily as you could with a btree structure. Cassandra works the same way as GAE by using the column store to maintain the index data.

Answer (score 32):

Assuming you have created index on the `author` field, from algorithmic point of view, the time complexity of `$in` operation is: `$(N*log(M))`, where `N` is the length of input array and `M` is the size of the collection.

The time complexity of `$in` operation will **not change** unless you change a database (Though I don't think any db can break `O(N*log(M))`).

However, from engineering point of view, if `N` goes to a big number, it is better to let your business logic server to simulate the `$in` operation, either by batch or one-by-one.

This is simply because: memory in database servers is way more valuable than the memory in business logic servers.

Answer (score 10):

If you build an index (ensureIndex) on the list element, it should be pretty quick.

Have you tried using `explain()`? Its a good, built-in way to profile your queries:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-Use%7B%7Bexplain%7D%7D.