# java mongodb morphia : not contains

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

How can I write query with morphia (or without it) to match all documents whose collections don't contain a child with some value? In my case the collection holds strings, something like this:

```
    myClass{
          Collection<String> collection;
          ...
    }
```

If I would like to search documents whose collection holds some value I would write something like this:

```
    query.and(
         ......
         query.criteria("collection").contains("search string").) 
        // or possible hasThisElement("search string")
    );
```

I can try to use **hasNoneOf** but I am worry about perfomance (it is designed for a collection input, and I have a single argument) and I would like to hear other suggestions.I am looking for something like **notContains**.  Thanks.

**Edit**

Possible [morphia wiki](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query) can be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasNoneOf` gets converted to `$nin`. I think that should be reasonably fast if you index the collection and each collection only contains a few dozen values.

The answer for `$in` should apply for your situation as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961447/573153
So I'd think your fine with this approach. If in doubt, do a mini-benchmark yourself.