# mongodb/mongoose The way to find an array of docs by ids. - Using $in or multiple findbyId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find docs with an array of ids. I have two way to do that

1. using `find({_id:{$in:arr}} , callback)`
2. using multiple `findById`, and use some async code wrapper to execute them together.

What I concern here is which one is better? For the server side seems the second needs more computing, but what about the database part?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you consider is a heavy operation for your system. Option 1 requires 1 DB call where as Option 2 requires several (depending on how many you fetch).

Anyways, option 1 seems to be a better option since it would return a cursor and you'd just be iterating over it. Where as for option 2 you'd need multiple db calls (probably be doing it in a loop) and it would be returning the data and closing the cursor.

The only time option 2 would benefit you is when you have just one value to find or you have special indexes and not just $in queries. Say index on attribute1, attribute2.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955160/mongo-in-operator-performance).

Comment: I guess you are right. What I am not sure before is the performance of a single find with $in towards that of multiple findbyids. (I has thought findbyid is special since "id" is involved)  Now I read this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483632/mongodb-via-mongoose-js-what-is-findbyid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483632/mongodb-via-mongoose-js-what-is-findbyid), the findbyid is only  for convenience.  And also as you point out, there would be way too many db calls with option 2.   I m convinced. Wait for a little while and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Read this as well > http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls

Comment: Wow! findOne could be slower than find().limit, very surprising to me! I learn! Thank you Syed!

Comment: Though there are no cursors inside the callback function using mongoose, the idea I guessed is similar. I definitely go with find.