# Get a list of documents from list of IDs

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a list of `_id`s of objects in a Mongo database. Using `pymongo`, what is the best way to get a the list of documents identified by these IDs?

I know that I can simply loop over the IDs and do `find_one` on each ID, but it seems inefficient to do one request for each ID.

```
def get_all(ids):
    return [coll.find_one({'_id': id}) for id in ids]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the keyword "$in"

```
return coll.find({"_id":{"$in": ids}})
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39567887/1485877), the complexity is `O(size_of_ids * log(size_of_collection))`.

Comment: With this solution, documents do not come back in the order they were supplied to `$in`. It looks like they come back sorted by key. This is probably a byproduct of an internal uniquify operation.