# MongoDB sort performance when used with $in query

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a collection `product` in my DB. Below is one sample document:

```
{
"sku_id":"12345678",
"priduct_name":"milk",
"product_rank":3,
"product_price": 2.4
}
```

There are 100k such unique documents in our collection. 
I want to query this collection using `$in` query, as shown below.

```
db.product.find({"sku_id" :{$in :["12345678","23213"]}}).sort( { product_rank: 1 } )
```

Our requirement is to search documents based on `$in` query and sort any field in document(asc or desc). 
I have created both forward and reverse index on all fields for this collection.

Note: This `sku_id` array inside `$in` query can have 1000+ sku_ids.

My doubt is if I use the filter like `$in` with an array of `sku_id` and get the sorted result on any field, will it use the index for sorting or will it sort at query time?

Answer (score 1):

Mongo allows you to find out if a query will use an index. As the find operation returns a cursor you can extend the method chain to include an [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) command which does exactly what you need. (suggest you use `db.product.find(...).sort(...).explain('executionStats')`)

> Will it use the index for sorting or will it sort at query time?

The index created on the `product_rank` will be used in the query but, not an index on the `sku_id` alone. Instead create a compound index with both `product_rank` and `sku_id`(asc and desc).

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Not sure about `$in` won't use index. 
I was reading through, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955160/mongo-in-operator-performance. This post says it actually uses index.

Comment: Yes right, I should have phrased it better, the `$in` will not use an index on `sku_id`. But if you create an index on both `product_rank` and `sku_id`. Your current query will use that. Edited answer to reflect this

Comment: @BikasKatwal it does use an index, not sure why Rakshith saying otherwise.