# Compare if ObjecticID already exist or not in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongo, I made `history` column array for each `user` to get the Id of specific card, so I would like to made a condition or not for knowing that :

[image]

To understand my code :

- find the ID user, find his `history` :
  if card ID already present => don't duplicate ID on this array
- but, if is not present :
  add the ID on his own `history` array.

My `req.body._id` is the `Id` value who the user submit

```
const forThisUser = { _id: req.user._id }
const condition = await User.find(forThisUser, {"history" : { $in : req.body._id}})

async function alreadyPresentOrNot(res, req){
  if(condition>0){
    console.log("Already present !")
    res.sendStatus(401);
}
else{
  console.log("Card not finding, add on array now !")
  await User.findOneAndUpdate(forThisUser, { $addToSet: { history: req.body._id } }, {upsert: true})
  res.sendStatus(201);
  }
}
```

I got this error :

> ERROR  Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just try using it in an array.
`const ids = [req.body._id];`
`const condition = await User.find(forThisUser, {"history" : { $in : [ids]}})`
Here is the official link that says you have to use `$in : [array]`
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html?

Comment: Hi, @khairul-hasan  i try ur code but it doesn't work, i don't very understand, why it need to put the`req.body._id` on array ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Monngoose's [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find):

Your query should be:

```
const forThisUser = { _id: req.user._id }
const condition = await User.find({...forThisUser, "history" : { $in : req.body._id}})
```

Find takes the filters argument as an object, which would be:

```
{ 
  _id: req.user._id,
  history: { $in: req.body._id } 
}
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but you may want to have a look at your [HTTP response codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) as well.

For example, for a duplicated entry you would return a `409 Conflict`, or a `400 Bad Request` not a `401 Unauthorized`.

And if the card is added you can return `200 Success` or `204 No Conntent`, unless you are creating the card resource in that same request your return `201 Created`

Comment: thank u for your reply, i try ur solution and is worked, but i don't know why but for some submit it takes time...

Comment: It is hard to determine why without the full code snippet

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961447/5078746 you might have big lists in your User.history collection, and then you might need to think of a different approach or use the mongodb's aggregation framework. Or you're just having issues in your Node.js code